# recipient receives same mail twice while sending mail in yii 1.1

Tags: email, yii

I am trying to send mail to recipient one at a time.My code is like this:

```
$message = new YiiMailMessage;
$message->view = "mail";
$params = array('sendEmail'=>$values);
$message->subject = $values['subject'];
$message->setBody($params, 'text/html');
$message->from =$values['email_from'] ;
$message->addTo($values['email_to']);
if(Yii::app()->mail->send($message)){
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success','Success sending email. ');
    $this->redirect(array('mail/admin'));

}else{
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','Error while sending email. ');
}
```

Mail is received by recipient but same mail is received twice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a create action to notify the user each time a new record is created. Verify Yii::app()->mail->send($message) appears one time in your action, for example:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model= new MyModel;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
     $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['SomeForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['SomeForm'];
        if($model->validate()){
        if($model->save()){

            $message = new YiiMailMessage;
            $message->setBody('<h1>mets-blog.com</h1>','text/html');
            $message->subject = 'Service';
            $message->addTo('mets@blog.com');
            $message->from = 'your@email.com' you want
            Yii::app()->mail->send($message);

            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

maybe you are calling your action twice in your controller by render your view.